# PDO rowCount() alternative

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am using PDO `rowCount()` to understand whenever an `UPDATE` was successfull or not.
The problem is that `rowCount(`) does not return anything in the case that the query was successfull but there was no row to update.

This is not good for me because in this case I run an `INSERT` and the mysql returns an error for duplicated keys.

What's the best way in PDO to know if a query was successfull, in this specific case, means when an `UPDATE` was successfull even though no rows were affected?

Thanks

Comment: a successful query means there was no error.

Comment: Yes but in this case after an UPDATE PDO will not return an error if nothing is found in the DB, will just return true. So I will not be able to understand if running an INSERT or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case of "XY problem". But luckily you managed to explain your *real* problem along with main question. You don't actually need no `rowcount()` here.

What you really need is a mysql specific `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query

Which will either insert or update the record based on whether it exists or not.

Comment: You did read that from the question? Must be the language barrier for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$stmt->execute() === true` to test if a query was successful.

Use `$stmt->rowCount() > 0` to see if there where any updates.

For example:

```
if( $stmt->execute() === true && $stmt->rowCount() > 0 )
```

Comment: The problem is that rowCount() returns 0 if row were matched but no fields were updated (already has the same values)

Comment: @Diego Pucci So the logical change to detect successful update statements is to leave out the second test. Is it that hard to understand?

Comment: @feeela you are not getting my question totally. Thanks anyway